# Complete the index and columns in pandas(DataFrame)?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a datafrmae.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10)}, index=np.arange(0,20,2))
# then I can create new dataframe and complete the index.
b = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(20))
b['a'] = a
# Now convert the index np.arange(0,20,2) to np.arange(20). Fill noexists value by np.nan.
```

But how can i do the same way to column? Suppose the column's dtype is int32 and names is np.arange(0,20,2).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, can you post an example of the result you're looking for?

Comment: @lascort Thanks, it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (a.reindex(b.index))
      a
0   0.0
1   NaN
2   1.0
3   NaN
4   2.0
5   NaN
6   3.0
7   NaN
8   4.0
9   NaN
10  5.0
11  NaN
12  6.0
13  NaN
14  7.0
15  NaN
16  8.0
17  NaN
18  9.0
19  NaN
```

Also can reindex columns:

```
a.columns = [0]
print (a.reindex(index=b.index, columns=np.arange(0,20,2)))
     0   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18
0   0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   3.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   4.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10  5.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
11  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
12  6.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
13  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
14  7.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
15  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
16  8.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
17  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
18  9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
19  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```